# Asking a yes/no question is closed as opinion

Tags: discussion

[It's questions like this one that really get to me.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101764/has-anyone-succeeded-with-a-low-price-offer-for-a-domain-name) I clearly ask for a yes or no answer but all the responses attempt to tell me how or why. Then my question is closed as "opinion" but you can't give opinion with a yes or no answer (though I am asking for details).

Why was this closed as opinion when I specifically ask for a yes/no answer and to relate their experience?

Comment: With respect of course. I like you. We get questions from people quite a lot where they want to get a domain name that someone holds for cheap or free. Many are looking for loop-holes, tricks, and the like. I know you have honest intent. There is no question on that! However, what I have learned over the years is that most of our users have little experience with trying to acquire an existing domain with some exception. While it is possible to acquire a domain this way, generally, it is not worth the effort simply because of monetizers being colossal butt heads. ;-) Again, with respect.

Comment: @closetnoc My intent was to find out if anyone had success because I was going to approach them with a low offer to see if they would respond but I didn't want to give them the impression it was of great value making them want to hold onto it even longer. I would rather ask on stackexchange than every other mostly amateur forum where you'd get every crazy answer you can think of...like reddit. btw, I like me, too. You picked a good one to like.

Comment: I know your intent was perfectly genuine! Here is a thought, if you approach them, tell them what you intend to do with the domain name and the value to you so that they can clearly see the value instead of imagining Internet riches and a new Bently. Think Yugo. Used Yugo. But do paint a realistic picture of the value of the domain name as you see it and let them decide. Be fair. Be honest. They may say, What the hell?? It is funny. People like to help people who are honest. Honest. Would I lie to you? Not without a punchline! Cheers!!

Comment: `...but all the responses attempt to tell me how or why`<- That's precisely what questions should elicit. As covered in our Help Center documentation on [Asking](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), questions should: `inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”` and `tend to have long, not short, answers`. As [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186530/what-close-reason-for-polling-questions) Meta question demonstrates, there are only a few close reasons available, so polling questions are often labeled as opinion-based (when not seeking recommendations) ...

Comment: since there isn't a right or wrong answer, and hence don't fit the vote & accept format of Stack Exchange sites very well.

Comment: ...but is perfect for chat.

Comment: Not sure why the down-votes. I cannot do much, but I can do something. Cheers!!

Answer (score 5):

Polling members for their experience means there cannot be a best answer. There is no right or wrong and no answer can be better than another. Such questions are not a good fit at this site or any Stack Exchange site.

And your question isn't really a yes or no question. The answer should always be yes otherwise they have no experience to share.